# Plotly X Axis Intervals

Tags: r, plot, plotly, visualize

I need to create plot with plotly but I want to determine x axis breaks intervals myself.

I need someting like this.

[image]

I searched a lot and couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the x-axis itself that's the issue here, but rather the number of bins. You can adjust that using `nbinsx` like:

```
plot_ly(x, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 20)
```

#### Example with some sample data after comment:

**Code 1:**

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
numbers <- rnorm(100,20, 20)
p1 <- plot_ly(x = ~numbers,type = "histogram")
p1
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
p2 <- plot_ly(x = ~numbers,type = "histogram", nbinsx=20)
p2
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
p3 <- plot_ly(x = ~numbers,type = "histogram", nbinsx=20)
p3
```

**Plot 3:**

[image]

**code 3:**

```
p3 <- plot_ly(x = ~numbers,type = "histogram", nbinsx=5)
p3
```

Comment: I want to create different intervals for x. Like  0-5(xbin=5) 5-20(xbin=15) 20-50(xbin=30)